# Instantiating array but keep getting IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to tally a count array to keep up with a set of 50 choices where there are three options for each choice. The count array should have 150 elements, per my instructor (3 x 50 = 150). But I keep getting an IndexOutofBounds Exception at line 55 (`index = thisChoice.get(i)`). I'm thinking that it must have something to do with how (or where?) I'm instantiating my count array at

```
line 50: int[] count = new int[students.get(0).getChoices().size()*3]
```

because the rest of the code came from my instructor and is presumably correct. Any ideas on what could be sending it out of bounds?

```
public class P1Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    ArrayList<Students> students = new ArrayList<Students>();
    ArrayList<String> choices = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File("Choices.txt"));
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("EitherOr.csv"));

    // Scan the first file.
    int choicesIndex = 0;
    while(scan1.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scan1.nextLine();
        choices.add(line);
        choicesIndex++;
    }
    scan1.close();

    // Scan the second file.
    int studentIndex = 0;
    while(scan2.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scan2.nextLine();
        String [] splits = line.split(","); 

        students.add(new Students(splits[0]));

        for(int i = 1; i < splits.length; i++){
            students.get(studentIndex).addChoices(Integer.parseInt(splits[i]));
        }
        studentIndex++;
    }
    scan2.close();

    // Instantiate and add to the count array.
    int index, countIndex;
    ArrayList<Integer> thisChoice;
    int[] count = new int[students.get(0).getChoices().size()*3];
    for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){
        countIndex = 1;
        thisChoice = students.get(i).getChoices();
        for(int j = 0; j < thisChoice.size(); j++){
            index = thisChoice.get(i);
            count[countIndex + index] = count[countIndex + index] + 1;
            countIndex+=3;
        }
    }

    // Display data.
    countIndex = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < choices.size(); i+=2){
        System.out.println(choices.get(i) + count[countIndex] + choices.get(i+1) + count[countIndex+1] + " Invalid: " + count[countIndex-1]);
        countIndex+=3;
    }
```

Comment: what's line 55?

Comment: Added it to my original post. Sorry that I left it out!

Comment: Look carefully at the line giving you the exception.  You made a typo.

Comment: At line 55? For the life of me I can't spot it. Should it be get(j) instead of get(i)?

Comment: You wrote the code, so you should know what it is supposed to do and if it should be `get(i)` or `get(j)`.

Comment: Checked it -- it should be get(j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI Please check second nested loop, it should be `j` instead of `i` .
also you haven't used `int j` in that loop.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        countIndex = 1;
        thisChoice = students.get(i).getChoices();
        for (int j = 0; j < thisChoice.size(); j++) {
            index = thisChoice.get(j);
            count[countIndex + index] = count[countIndex + index] + 1;
            countIndex += 3;
        }
    }
```